# Bootstrap Popover dismiss on body click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using some of bootstrap popover in my html. I just want to disapear the popover on body click or html click

```
$(function(){
    $('[data="popover"]').popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $($(this).data('popover-content')).removeClass('hide');
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
trigger : "focus"
```

or

```
data-trigger="focus"
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/93nyuqyf/**

explained here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples, section "*Dismiss on next click*".

Answer (score 0):

Add the `data-trigger` attribute to the actual popover, and set it to `focus`, like so...

```
<a href="#" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Click anywhere in the document to close this popover">Click me</a>
```

Snippet using this to demonstrate...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <a href="#" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Click anywhere in the document to close this popover">Click me</a>
</div>
```

If you're struggling have a read through this page, this was where the answer came from

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp